# mod-rewrite to work with oth server and userdir

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Apache mod_rewrite and userdir.
I want to write a .htaccess that works everywhere, is there a way to remove the RewriteBase or set it up using Apache variable ?

Here is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /~leo/lstronic/v2/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . ./index.php [QSA,L]
```

I also need to keep the relative URL, that's how I do this :

```
$config['root_directory']=__DIR__;
$config['project_subdirectory']=str_replace("/home/leo/public_html/","/~leo/",$config['root_directory']);
//$config['project_subdirectory']=str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],"",$config['root_directory']);
```

Is there a way to make the two last lines working everywhere ?

Léo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to generate `RewriteBase` dynamically in an env variable and use it in your rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . %{ENV:BASE}index.php [L]
```

Comment: That fixed the Apache problem I had